# Apache, PHP, Nodejs running on Fedora, routing to both php and nodejs depending on selected domain

Tags: php, node.js, apache, fedora

I use Digital Ocean droplet (maybe it can be helpful information to solve my problem).

My config is this:

- Fedora 22 [[link](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/Release_Notes/index.html)]
- Apache 2.4 [[link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/)]
- PHP 5.6.11 [[link](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.11)]
- MariaDB 10.0.20 [[link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-10020-release-notes/)]
- phpMyAdmin 4.4.12 [[link](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/)]
- Node 0.12.7 [[link](http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/07/10/node-v0-12-7-stable/)]

All of the above applications are in their default "after installation" state.

Currently PHP is running on port 80, nodejs is running on port 3000. So I have to type:

- `mydomain.com` for php
- `mydomain.com:3000` for nodejs

What I would want to do is this:

if I enter `someDomainForPhp.com/` I go to php default location which is `/var/www/html/`

if I enter `otherDomainforNode.com/` I go to node default location which is `/root/`

So from what I understand apache would have to do some internal port rerouting to accomplish this task.

I have been following many guides on the internet describing how to do it, but i think they are for people that have some basic knowledge on the subject. I am extremely new and "green" to this and im struggling with it.

If someone is willing to help, I could use following informations:

- which files to edit
- where they are
- how to edit them
- if any additional modules need to be installed, what are their names

---

### EDIT 03.08.2015

I have googled and tried following way:

```
<VirtualHost 109.74.199.47:80> # server ip address or *
    ServerAdmin davy.brion@thatextramile.be # any email address
    ServerName thatextramile.be # domain name
    ServerAlias www.thatextramile.be # any domain alias

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/ 
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I put it to this file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, at the very bottom. Many people reported that this method worked for them however if i tried it, i got `503 error` while accessing domain. So i googled for this 503 error and i found that some guy had similiar problem and he claimed that he made it to work by modyfing `Location` tags in following way:

```
<Location /path/of/my/project> # for me it would be /root/
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/ 
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
```

When I tried that, server acted like there was no virtual host directive at all, by accessing domain i was served with my regular `/var/www/html/index.php` file from apache, no proxy, no port change.

I also read that localhost is bad way, it should be `127.0.0.1`, however this doesn't change anything.

I didn't change any default configuration, I only added virtualhost directive to httpd conf. I am also sure that all needed modules like mod proxy are enabled, I searched through fedora 20 documentation and checked server status, they are by default included and enabled. This really seems odd that for some people it just is enough to add above lines. For me none of it worked, I either face 503 error and have no idea how to fix it or have not proxy at all. I hope someone will come through and help beginner dev in need ;)

---

### EDIT 04.08.2015

I was doing research and I found that some people experienced issues related to `chmod` settings placed on directories that are root locations for php and nodejs. It did not seem very logic to me but I tried it anyway, I have changed (for testing purposes) chmods to "allow all" configuration for all directories related to both applications. It did not help at all.

I also have read the blog where someone claimed that problem may be that I am only including proxy routing to port 3000 and i did not create a rule for regular php to be displayed. Tutorial was showing that apart from rule created for nodejs it also should contain this:

```
<VirtualHost 109.74.199.47:80> # server ip address or *
    ServerAdmin davy.brion@thatextramile.be # any email address
    ServerName thatextramile.be # domain name
    ServerAlias www.thatextramile.be # any domain alias
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>
```

So first rule is for routing to port 3000 for nodejs and this one is working for php. The problem is that when I implemented this rule I have infinite loop and server never loads. So I have 503 error when i enter domain prepared for nodejs and I have 502 error when I try to access domain for php.

After reading I have done I think I can point where problem could be, but still I could use a help regarding precise solution.

- could be linux firewall blocking port other then 80 (in this case 3000) and maybe after adding some exception to firewall problem will be solved
- could be that my nodejs server.js script is faulty

This is server.js file for testing. It is started infinitely using node forever module:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: I can help to a point since it's been a while since I used Apache, hopefully it will steer you to a right direction. You need 2 subdomains, in Apache it's called a Virtual Host. Then, each subdomain will **proxy** the request to appropriate handler. Ideally, you would have PHP served via FCGI instead mod_php. I think you need `mod_proxy` for this to work. File to edit is probably `httpd.conf`, you edit it with a regular text editor.

Comment: ok i understand, so what do i actially have to do to make it work, what to open and what to edit there? ;)

Comment: I see, you need an entire block of code.. well, I'm rusty there, I don't really know so I'd have to google-fu it as well :) until someone more experienced comes along, I'm afraid you'll either have to wait or google using the terms I provided, sorry :/

Comment: You can do this with ports, but it's much cleaner to do it with a separate IP address.

Comment: This really doesn't tell much to me, can you present answer with possible solution how it suppose to work, be written and where, as i said before im new to this. I can tell that i have 2 different domains connected to this server so i can utilize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First few words of explanation:

1. Before declaring `<VirtualHost>` directive you need to add `NameVirtualHost *`. Instead of `*` you can precisely define which domain/ip you are referring to. `*` will of course work but it is considered to be less secure and slower.
2. In order to allow proxy to be passed - you need to define directive `<Proxy>` and the only problem with your definition is `Allow from all`. This syntax is for apache 2.2, you are using apache 2.4 so according to [upgreading docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html) this should be used instead `Require all granted`.
3. `<Location>` tags in your case should be as you had at the beginning, only with single slash `<Location />`. The reason being is that you are `not` accessing your application via extra namespace, you are accessing it by entering straight domain name.
4. If you want to access php files on port `80` with `phpdomain.com` and node.js server on port `3000` with `nodejsdomain.com`, then you should `not` create 2 virtual hosts. You create only one that in case you enter `nodejsdomain.com` will open a port 3000. You would need second and more virtual hosts only if you would be using more node.js servers or other platforms. Because of the fact that you created it, you ended up in infinite loop.

The `main` reason why your proxy doesn't work is because of port 3000 which by default is blocked on `SELinux`. So first run this command `semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 3000`. (if you are not logged in as root type `sudo` before above syntax).

and then use virtual host directive:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nodejsdomain.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i will try this solution in a moment and get back to you